# Given a vector $v = [a, b, c] $ which lies in the plane defined by $dx + ey + fz + g = 0,$ does the equation $ad + be + cf = 0$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question was actually answered for me, but I am unclear about the details of the explanation.  My original thought was that if the vector in question lies in the plane, then the equation $da + eb + fc + g = 0$ must hold because the vector given must obey the plane equation.  However, I was informed that a plane's coefficients are derived from the vector normal to that plane.  Therefore, the vector $[d, e, f]$ is normal to the plane, meaning the equation $ad + be + cf = 0$ does hold because the scalar product of the given vector and this normal vector must be zero.

Can someone clear up why my reasoning about the equation $da + eb + fc + g = 0$ is incorrect?  Am I confusing a fundamental difference between vectors and points?

Answer (score 0):

well, i will try. i think you are confusing the point $(a,b,c)$ is on the plane $dx +ey  + fz + g = 0$ with the vector $(a,b,c)^T$ being on the plane. what the vectors $(a,b, c)^T$ is on the plane means that two points $(a_1, b_1, c_1) , (a_2, b_2, c_2)$ the difference vector $(a_1-a_2, b_1 - b_2, c_1 - c_2)$ is on the plane. if you put the point $(a_1, b_1, c_1$ you get $da_1+eb_1 + fc_1 + g = 0$  write another with with the subscript $1$ replaced by $2$ and subtract, then you $(a_1-a_2)d+(b_1-b_2)e + (c_1-c_2)f = 0$ the vector $(a_1-a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1-c_2)^T$ is orthogonal to the vector $(d, e, f)^T.$